# MySQL Search Against Not working on Small strings

Tags: mysql

OK, I have a table like so: [http://i.imgur.com/IPUSe.png](https://i.imgur.com/IPUSe.png)

[image]

I'm trying to get a match in the `combined_names` coloumn upon a MySQL search query..

and I use it to search using this query: `SELECT * FROM players WHERE match(combined_names) against('Lin')`

Upon running the query in phpmyadmin, I get this: `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0005 sec )`

Hmm... let's try a different row! `SELECT * FROM players WHERE match(combined_names) against('Dejan')` gives me `Showing rows 0 - 0 ( 1 total, Query took 0.0007 sec) [id: 1 - 1]` So it works!

Well, let's try changing `Lin` in both `combined_names` and `forename` to ... `Tester` so then we do: `SELECT * FROM players WHERE match(combined_names) against('Tester')`

I got it? I get: `Showing rows 0 - 0 ( 1 total, Query took 0.0006 sec) [id: 3 - 3]`

Weird. After changing `Lin` to `Tester`, it works... why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [ft_min_word_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len)=3, restart your mysql server and rebuild your indexes.

ft_min_word_len defaults to 4

Use `REPAIR TABLE tbl_name QUICK` to rebuild the fulltext index.